# Rails validation exclusion with routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rake, rspec-rails

I want to test that a user is invalid if the username equals one of the first routing blocks.
I spec it in rspec at the moment this way:

```
it "is not valid with a excluded username" do
  `bundle exec rake routes`.scan(/\s\/(\w+)/).flatten.compact.uniq.each do |route|
    user.username = route
    user.should_not be_valid
  end
end
```

The thing is, this slows down my specs, is there a better way to spec if every first route element is excluded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing that slows down your specs is `bundle exec rake routes`, because it loads rails environment once again. To prevent this you can extract the code that displays routes from actual rake task (it can be found in [rails github repo](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/tasks/routes.rake)). With those modifications your spec could look like that:

```
it "is not valid with a excluded username" do
  Rails.application.routes.routes.map(&:path).join("\n").scan(/\s\/(\w+)/).flatten.compact.uniq.each do |route|
    # blahblah
  end
end
```